# Unclear theorem about unitary transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation, unitary-matrices

I am currently working on quantum finite automata, when I came across a [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304397509000711?token=9AA8DDB8931C3F86FADDBA4F5652A45753B018FE9AC16E4E0AE12D246FD02D32C7E045373E622EC09E3927E74B81B76C) by Ambainis and Nahimovs. I am having some struggle with the "theorem from linear algebra" stated by them in Theorem 1 (the $|q_i \rangle$ are unit vectors):

> Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m$ be such that $\|\alpha_1 \|^2 + ... + \|\alpha_m \|^2  = 1$. Then,
>
> 1. there is a unitary transformation $U_1$ such that $U_1 |q_1 \rangle$ = $\alpha_m |q_m \rangle$ + ... + $\alpha_m |q_m \rangle$.
> 2. there is a unitary transformation $U_2$ such that, for all $i \in \lbrace 1,...,m \rbrace$, $U_2 |q_i \rangle$ is equal to $\alpha_i |q_1 \rangle$ plus some combination of $|q_2 \rangle,...,|q_m \rangle$.
>
> In the second case, we also have $U_2 (\alpha_i |q_1 \rangle + ... + \alpha_m |q_m \rangle) = |q_1 \rangle$.

While the first part is clear to me, I do not see why/how the second statement is conform to their subsequent remark. Writing $U_2 |q_i \rangle = \alpha_i |q_1 \rangle + \sum_{k=2}^m \beta^{(i)}_k |q_k \rangle$, $U_2$ should be unitary if $\sum_{k=2}^m | \beta^{(i)}_k |^2 = 1 - | \alpha_i |^2$ for all $i \in \lbrace 1,...,m \rbrace$. Therefore I think, it is always possible to define $U_2$ in this way indeed.

With that in mind, one would have:
$$
U_2 (\alpha_i |q_1 \rangle + ... + \alpha_m |q_m \rangle) = \sum_{i=1}^m (| \alpha_i |^2 |q_1 \rangle) + \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \sum_{k=2}^m | \beta^{(i)}_k |^2 \\ = |q_1 \rangle + \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \sum_{k=2}^m | \beta^{(i)}_k |^2.
$$
But this would contradict their remark, unless the latter term in the above equation is always zero (otherwise $U_2$ would not even be unitary). If so, is it generally possible to define the $\beta^{(i)}_k$ in this way? I got some results for the case that m=2 by solving a system of linear equations but this procedure seems not practical for higher dimensions. Or is there a contradiction?

Comment: You should use \rangle for a right angle bracket.

Comment: Reformulate your statements in a matrix form. The first statement says that for any given $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ there is a unitary matrix having them as its first column. The second statement is about the first row.

Comment: Thank you, @8k14! It turned out that the proof is pretty simple in this formulation.